# Radio button binding on razor page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have the following radio buttons on  my Razor page:

```
<div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <input asp-for="CodingLookup.CodingOption" type="radio" name="tele" value="tele0" />
                        <label for="tele0">Not coding.</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <input asp-for="@Model.CodingLookup.CodingChangesNotRequired" type="radio" name="tele" value="tele1" />
                        <label for="tele1">I have reviewed* my 2021/2022 coding forms and will not be requesting any changes for 2022/2023.</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <input asp-for="@Model.CodingLookup.CodingChangesRequired" type="radio" name="tele" value="tele2" />
                        <label for="tele2">I have reviewed* my 2021/2022 coding forms and changes are required. I will submit revised 2022/2023 coding forms </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <input asp-for="@Model.CodingLookup.NotCompletedCodingForm" type="radio" name="tele" value="tele3" />
                        <label for="tele3">I have not previously completed coding forms but will be coding in 2022/2023. I will submit new coding forms .</label>
                    </div>
```

I have the following model classes:

```
public partial class EmployeeInfo
    {
    
      public int EmployeeInfoId { get; set; }
       public virtual CodingLookup? CodingLookup { get; set; }
    }
    
    public partial class CodingLookup
{
    public int CodingLookupId { get; set; }

    public bool CodingOption { get; set; }

    public bool CodingChangesRequired { get; set; }
    public bool CodingChangesNotRequired { get; set; }

    public bool NotCompletedCodingForm { get; set; }

    public virtual List<EmployeeInfo> EmployeeInfos { get; } = new List<EmployeeInfo>();
}
```

I can change the above CodingLookup class if needed. I basically put all the options in Model class too. When I select any option and click on submit
button, the value of codingLookup is null in the HTTPPost. This is the first time, I am using radioButtons.

**UPDATE:**

I also tried to change the Model class this way:

```
    public partial class EmployeeInfo
        {
        
          public int EmployeeInfoId { get; set; }
           public virtual CodingLookup? CodingLookup { get; set; }
        }
    
       
       public partial class CodingLookup
       {
           public int CodingLookupId { get; set; }
    
           public string CodingOption { get; set; }
           public string[] CodingOptions = new[] { "Coding Test1", "Coding Test2", "Coding Test3", "Coding Test4"};}
    }
      public virtual List<EmployeeInfo> EmployeeInfos { get; } = new List<EmployeeInfo>();
   }
```

This is my Razor code:

```
@model AckPackage.Models.EmployeeInfo

<div class="form-group row">

  <div class="col">

                     @foreach (var x in Model.CodingLookup.CodingOptions)

                        {

                        <input type="radio" asp-for="CodingLookup.CodingOption" value="@Model.CodingLookup.CodingOption" />

                        @Model.CodingLookup.CodingOption

                        <br />

                        }



                </div>

                </div>
```

Above code does not work either. I just want to display all the names with radio button on my page and then get the value of those radio button in the HTTPPost. below is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(EmployeeInfo employeeInfo)

    {

   }
```

**Error:**

As soon as I start running the code, i get this error:

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you put both(EmployeeInfo and CodingLookup) of the namespace here? and is the Razor page written this way? (@model test.Models.EmployeeInfo)

Comment: Yes, it is. This is in the top of my controller class: @model AckPackage.Models.EmployeeInfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change your view like below:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col">
        @foreach (var x in Model.CodingLookup.CodingOptions)
        {
            <input type="radio" asp-for="CodingLookup.CodingOption" value="@x" />
            @x
            <br />
        }
    </div>

</div>
```

---

A whole working demo you could follow:

Model

```
public partial class EmployeeInfo
{
    public int EmployeeInfoId { get; set; }
    public virtual CodingLookup? CodingLookup { get; set; }
}
public partial class CodingLookup
{
    public int CodingLookupId { get; set; }
    public string CodingOption { get; set; }
    public string[] CodingOptions = new[] { "Coding Test1", "Coding Test2", "Coding Test3", "Coding Test4" };
    public virtual List<EmployeeInfo> EmployeeInfos { get; } = new List<EmployeeInfo>();
}
```

View(Views/Home/Create.cshtml)

```
@model EmployeeInfo

<form asp-action="Create" method="post">
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col">
        @foreach (var x in Model.CodingLookup.CodingOptions)
        {
            <input type="radio" asp-for="CodingLookup.CodingOption" value="@x" />
            @x
            <br />
        }
    </div>

</div>
<input type="submit" value="post" />
</form>
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
    {
        return View(new EmployeeInfo() { CodingLookup=new CodingLookup()});
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(EmployeeInfo employeeInfo)
    {
        //do your stuff....
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I use the existing model to pass the value of Tele. This is on top of my controller class: @model AckPackage.Models.EmployeeInfo

Comment: I posted an updated Model class.

Comment: Hi @Rena, As soon as I start running the code, I get the NULL exception error. I pasted the error in my original post under error.

Comment: Hi @rimi, pls see my HttpGet `Create` action for render the view, did you pass the model in your code like what I did?

Comment: Hi @Rena, When I do this, return View(new EmployeeInfo() { CodingLookup=new CodingLookup()}); I dont get an error, but I dont get any EmployeeInfo either. I am passing lot of employee Information like firstName, Lastname and other things related to employee. All that information becomes empty.

Comment: In my Create, I am passing             employee = await _employeeService.GetEmployeeByEmployeeNumber(up.EmployeeId);

Comment: Hi @rimi, so how is your service like? The error caused because the `CodingLookup` is null, you need check it.

Comment: I update my original post and put my Get method. My get method has lot of code.

Comment: Hi @rimi, You need share what is the `GetEmployeeByEmployeeNumber` service in your original post.

Comment: Or you can try to change the property to :`public virtual CodingLookup CodingLookup { get; set; }= new CodingLookup();` in EmployeeInfo.

Comment: public virtual CodingLookup CodingLookup { get; set; }= new CodingLookup(); worked. Thanks for all your help!!